# WYSIWYG frontend display as HTML

Tags: php, html, wysiwyg

I have an HTML WYSIWYG that is added into the db using

`'page_description'    => htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('content'));`

When I view on the frontend I get [image]

How can I decode it so it shows as HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function that is intended in PHP to be a sort of inverse to `htmlspecialchars`/`htmlentities` is [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `htmlspecialchars` bit. That's converting `<` into `&lt;` so it prints out as the actual symbol, ignored by the browser as the start of an HTML tag.

```
'page_description' => $this->input->post('content');
```

From: https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars

```
The translations performed are:

'&' (ampersand) becomes '&amp;'
'"' (double quote) becomes '&quot;' when ENT_NOQUOTES is not set.
"'" (single quote) becomes '&#039;' (or &apos;) only when ENT_QUOTES is set.
'<' (less than) becomes '&lt;'
'>' (greater than) becomes '&gt;'
```